# Where should I keep my test assets?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I am developing a project about an MP3 player in Python and I have a set of functions and classes that should be tested against real MP3 files.
What directory structure would you suggest for keeping my test MP3 files?

Those files should stay with project and anybody who clones the project should be able to run the tests. This is what I use currently but I'm not sure if it's good enough according to best practices:

```
  /project-root
      /src
          player.py
          utils.py
      /test
          player_test.py
          utils_test.py
          /assets
              Sample1.mp3
              Sample2.mp3
              Corrupt.mp3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) are some recommendations on project structure. Basically there is more flexibility around the repo structure compared to guidelines for writing and organizing modules.

I look at the [pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas) structure and they have.

```
/pandas
  /src
  /tests
      /data
          somedata.csv
```

Others use "files" so I think "assets" is fine, while others have "data" in a another folder outside of "tests". Your structure looks pretty good although most seem to use "tests" instead of "test" if you want to be nitpicky.